# Integrating a function of a random variable; $\int g(X) dP$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-analysis

Assume a random variable $X$ on probability space $\Omega$, taking values in $\mathbb{R}$ with some known distribution $F(dX)$. Assume also a function of the random variable, $g(X)$. Does then the following relation hold true?:
$$
\int_\Omega g(X) dP = \int_\Omega g(X)F(dX) = \int_\mathbb{R}g(x)F(dx)
$$

I know that the expectation of a random variable can be defined in a similar fashion $$
E(X) = \int_\Omega X dP = \int_\mathbb{R}xF(dx)
$$
but I am not sure whether this translates to the case with a function of $X$, $g(X)$.

Comment: Isn't it just the [LOTUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician)? By the way, function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ must be measurable.

Comment: @V.C. Certainly looks that way

Comment: The expression F(dX) should be avoided since it confuses the source set and the target space.